# Дубы — дубрава, а сосны — бор.

Tags: этимология

Почему сосновый лес называется бор? Есть слово "сосняк", но обычно это означает небольшой лесок, а вот большой лесной массив — все-таки бор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Почему" - не знаю, вряд ли может юыть какая-то причинно-следственная связь между "сосной" и "дубравой".

А если вообще обсудить...

Во многих близкородственных  славянских "бор" (или производные) имеет значение "сосна" или "сосновый лес". Этимология бор восходит к индоевропеским морфам с общим значением игла, хвоя, ель и т.д.

"Сосна" же в русском занчении ограничена восточнославянскими, возводят к морфам означающим цвет (седой, серый, светлокоричневый), либо "смола", "сок".

Поэтому можно предположить, что это слово "сосна" просто вытеснило исконное "бор" для обозначения дерева.